# Databinding Button Content to a static resource fails

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to design a set of icons in a Silverlight 4 User Control's ressources, and then display these on a button.

I have

```
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <Rectangle x:Key="Icon1" Fill="Black" Width="10" Height="10" />            
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and

```
<Button x:Name="Button1"
        Width="50" Height="50"                        
        Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Icon1}}" />
```

I also tried  `... Content="{StaticResource Icon1}"`. Both show fine in the XAML Designer of VS 2010, but fail when I try to run it with a XAMLParseException. The first one complains about the argument not falling into the expected range, the second one simply says "Failed to assign property". Copying the Rectangle into the Buttons content directly works fine.

Where is the problem? I thought I finally understood this.. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a template instead of setting the content anyway.

```
<ControlTemplate
    x:Key="IconTemplate">
       <Rectangle x:Key="Icon1" Fill="Black" Width="10" Height="10" />   
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="IconStyle" TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource IconTemplate}"/>
</Style>

<Button x:Name="Button1"
        Width="50" Height="50"                        
        Style="{StaticResource IconStyle}" />
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'd like to know, why you would choose this approach instead of setting the content directly?

Comment: A few reasons;

1) It seems to be the way that MS wants us to make use of WPF
2) This can be tested better, to ensure that the elements (templates & styles) are available to the control
3) To me this is a more scalable approach, but that might be debatable

Comment: I tried this approach, but it seems that my (triggerbehavior) VisualStates of the Control inside the template isn't maintained. any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by setting the ContentTemplate to a DataTemplate:

```
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Icon1">
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="10" Height="10" />            
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Button:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1"
        Width="50" Height="50"                        
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icon1}" />
```

Setting the Template on the Button works too, but I believe you have to replace the entire template for the control.  This approach lets you keep the existing control template.

Comment: ...I did this in WPF but I think it works for Silverlight too.